# What is the functionality of the Bitwise and Bitshift operators in Java?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I understand what the bitwise and bitshift operators in java *do*, but i dont understand what their practical use is. For instance, when is it useful to use
" ~, <<, >>, >>>, &, ^,| " to modify or compare the bits of values?

Comment: Think of what your answer would be if someone asked "what is the practical use for multiplication". I don't even know what to say to that other than "you just need it sometimes". Same with bitwise operations.

Answer (score 1):

**Bit fields (flags)**

They're the most efficient way of representing something whose state is defined by several "yes or no" properties. ACLs are a good example; if you have let's say 4 discrete permissions (read, write, execute, change policy), it's better to store this in 1 byte rather than waste 4. These can be mapped to enumeration types in many languages for added convenience.

**Communication over ports/sockets**

Always involves checksums, parity, stop bits, flow control algorithms, and so on, which usually depend on the logic values of individual bytes as opposed to numeric values, since the medium may only be capable of transmitting one bit at a time.

**Compression, Encryption**

Both of these are heavily dependent on bitwise algorithms. Look at the deflate algorithm for an example - everything is in bits, not bytes.

**Finite State Machines**

I'm speaking primarily of the kind embedded in some piece of hardware, although they can be found in software too. These are combinatorial in nature - they might literally be getting "compiled" down to a bunch of logic gates, so they have to be expressed as AND, OR, NOT, etc.

**Graphics**

There's hardly enough space here to get into every area where these operators are used in graphics programming.  XOR (or ^) is particularly interesting here because applying the same input a second time will undo the first. Older GUIs used to rely on this for selection highlighting and other overlays, in order to eliminate the need for costly redraws. They're still useful in slow graphics protocols (i.e. remote desktop).

Those were just the first few examples I came up with - this is hardly an exhaustive list.